# Meaning of "ascertainment" in a medical article

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

SEARCH for Diabetes in Youth is a multicenter study that conducts population-based **ascertainment of youth** with clinically diagnosed, non-gestational diabetes who are <20 at the time of diagnosis.

**Cases are ascertained** from geographically defined populations in Ohio, Colorado, South Carolina and Washington, Indian Health Service beneficiaries from four American Indian populations, and enrollees in several health plans in California and Hawaii.

I know what ascertain means, but I can't understand the meaning of the word "ascertainment" in this context. Can you please help me put this phrase in other words for clear understanding.

Comment: This is *ascertain*, a verb you may find in any dictionary, with the suffix *-ment*, which transforms it into a noun: the act of ascertaining.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'd have expected ***assessment*** in the cited context, so assuming the writer is a competent native speaker, it's at least *possible* they've deliberately chosen a different word for some reason. Come to that, what exactly is "youth" here, and what are they ascertaining/assessing that's somehow different to simply asking the study subjects how old they are?

Comment: StoneyB, I understand to "ascertain a fact", but I can't render into target language to "ascertain youth". Does it mean to "examine" or "find" them or somethin else?

Comment: In this context "youth" are children and adolescents, who came to study centre with their parents to report about their disease

Comment: @vasily.m.biryukov: If that is indeed the case, I would say it's a non-idiomatic usage. More credible (but still unlikely) would be the plural form ***youths***, but to my mind ***young people*** would be far more natural for that sense. It's worth noting that the collocation [ascertainment of youth](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ascertainment+of+youth%22) doesn't even appear *once* in the entire Google Books corpus, so I'm inclined to doubt there's any domain-specific usage involved here. Just a writer with some unusual ideas about use of English.

Comment: ...on the other hand, [assessment of young people](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22ascertainment+of+youth%22#tbm=bks&q=%22assessment+of+young+people%22) occurs over 20,000 times.

Comment: For the record, I am a native speaker of (American) English and regularly read medical research, and I have _no idea what this passage means_.  I have some guesses, but no certainty.

Comment: Although I'm not sure it's correct, _youth_ is sometimes used as a plural, especially when referring to a category of people rather than a finite set of young people.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am certain that it's not synonymous with "assessment".  Assessment means, in a medical context, something other that what is being described here.  This study is finding youth that qualify as study participants, which can only happen well after the youth were assessed by somebody else.

Comment: OP, my educated guess is that by "ascertainment", the authors mean that their study/organization ascertains whether individual youths qualify as  study subjects for their research.  But I don't know that for sure.

Comment: I just found a link that says _youth_ is correct.  "_Many nouns in English have a plural form either with an s/es ending or without...If youth is being used collectively, do not add the s._"  See http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/singular-vs-plural/plurals-of-odd-words/.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, in medical research "youth" means something specific that is not synonymous with "young people":  http://www.un.org/esa/socdev/documents/youth/fact-sheets/youth-definition.pdf

Comment: Выявление is the word (discovery and confirming the diagnosis.

Comment: @V.V. Is it though?  I don't think what these researchers is doing is confirming the diagnosis.  It doesn't sound to me that by "ascertainment" they mean they're checking into whether the diagnosis given by the youths' medical providers is correct.  It sounds more to me like "identifying in the population".

Comment: I'm also a native English speaker, and I believe that in this case _ascertainment_ *IS* intended to be synonymous with _assessment_ or _examination_ .  They are going to find people who qualify for the study, and each person who qualifies will be ascertained, i.e., examined/assessed.  As I read it, the ascertainment is what will be done *after* they qualify as a study participant.  The ascertainment is not what qualifies them as a participant.

Comment: @Codeswitcher: Der... There are so many basic errors in that link I don't think it's likely there really *is* any justification for the non-standard syntactic usage here. It's simply not idiomatic to say things like *I study youth with diabetes*, and the fact that the *category* is explicitly defined there as meaning "young people aged 15-24" doesn't justify the syntactic change.

Comment: Yes, finding out such cases @Codeswitcher.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Darryl, Codeswitcher, V.V., thank you for helping me understand that this collocation is unusual for the English language, I think I can understand its meaning now!

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's perfectly idiomatic to say "I study youth with diabetes" _in medical research._

Comment: I don't know about the medical domain, but in everyday usage it's not at all uncommon to hear things like "I work with troubled youth."  It's certainly more common than "troubled youths" or "troubled young people", at least in the western United States.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ascertainment** refers to the sampling parameters in use when finding cases for a study. One must avoid so-called "ascertainment bias" that would skew the statistical results.